# How to run function of parent window when child window closes?

Tags: javascript, window

I am calling the javascript window.open() function to load another url in a pop up. Once the users is finished it takes them to the last page that has a link that says close window that calls the window.close() function. Now when that page closes I need to update something in the original page that opened the window. Is there any way to do this? I have to call a function that is in my original page.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112340/how-to-run-function-of-parent-window-when-child-window-closes

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can somehow try this:

Spawned window:

```
window.onunload = function (e) {
    opener.somefunction(); //or
    opener.document.getElementById('someid').innerHTML = 'update content of parent window';
};
```

Parent Window:

```
window.open('Spawn.htm','');
window.somefunction = function(){

}
```

You should not do this on the parent, otherwise opener.somefunction() will not work,
doing window.somefunction makes somefunction as public:

```
function somefunction(){

}
```

Comment: +1, helped me at the right time. Writing window.somefunction = function{ .... } is same as writing function somefunction() { .... }

Comment: This doesnt work on IE if the the spawned window and the parent window are not from the same domain

Comment: Thanks for great reply. But this code is not working on IE. How this works on IE browser.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I've been looking for. It worked on both FF and IE for me.

Comment: Great, It success

Answer (score 10):

This is an old post, but I thought I would add another method to do this:

```
var win = window.open("http://www.google.com");

var winClosed = setInterval(function () {

    if (win.closed) {
        clearInterval(winClosed);
        foo(); //Call your function here
    }

}, 250);
```

You don't have to modify the contents or use any event handlers from the child window.

Answer (score 9):

You probably want to use the '[onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload)' event.  It will allow you call a function in the parent window from the child immediately before the child window closes.

So probably something like this:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    window.parent.functonToCallBeforeThisWindowCloses();
};
```

Comment: ok that looks like what I am looking for but how will it know what window I am talking about. For instance if I do window.open() and then i add that below it will it know its that window or how do i attach it to that window?

Comment: You'll put that onbeforeunload in a script tag in your child window's HTML. Since the child window only has one parent the browser automatically knows what that parent window is.

Comment: so if I have a function called doSomething() in the parent window but its not defined in the child window it will still allow me to run it?

Comment: Yep. You'd do something like 'window.parent.doSomething()'.  Though you may want/have to use the apply() JavaScript function (http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/function.shtml) to actually make the call to the parent function.

Comment: Thanks for the help. You go me in the right place but I accepted the other answer because it solved my issue completely. i am going to give you a plus one though

Answer (score 4):

The answers as they are require you to add code to the spawned window. That is unnecessary coupling.

```
// In parent window
var pop = open(url);
pop.onunload = function() {
  // Run your code, the popup window is unloading
  // Beware though, this will also fire if the user navigates to a different
  // page within thepopup. If you need to support that, you will have to play around
  // with pop.closed and setTimeouts
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old, but I found that this really works well:

```
window.onunload = function() {
    window.opener.location.href = window.opener.location.href;
};
```

The `window.onunload` part was the hint I found googling this page.  Thanks, @jerjer!

Answer (score 0):

Along with jerjer answer(top), sometimes in your parent window and child window are not both external or both internal you will see a problem of opener undefined, and you cannot access parent page properties, see [window.opener is undefined on Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23562044/window-opener-is-undefined-on-internet-explorer)

Answer (score -2):

Check following [link](http://anishantha87.blogspot.com/2013/12/how-to-run-function-of-parent-window.html). This would be helpful too..

In Parent Window:

```
function OpenChildAsPopup() {
        var childWindow = window.open("ChildWindow.aspx", "_blank",
        "width=200px,height=350px,left=200,top=100");
        childWindow.focus();
 }

function ChangeBackgroudColor() {
        var para = document.getElementById('samplePara');
        if (para !="undefied") {
            para.style.backgroundColor = '#6CDBF5';
        }
 }
```

Parent Window HTML Markup:

```
<div>
  <p id="samplePara" style="width: 350px;">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
  </p><br />
 <asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="Open Child Window" 
         runat="server" OnClientClick="OpenChildAsPopup();"/>
</div>
```

In Child Window:

```
// This will be called when the child window is closed.     
  window.onunload = function (e) {
        opener.ChangeBackgroudColor();
        //or you can do
        //var para = opener.document.getElementById('samplePara');
        //if (para != "undefied") {
        //    para.style.backgroundColor = '#6CDBF5';
        //}
    };
```