# Trying to handle a close window event on child window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a website that opens a new window.  I am trying to trigger `onclose` event on the child window (if the user closed the window the parent window will alert it).

I found a stackoverflow question regarding that problem at: [How to run function of parent window when child window closes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777864/how-to-run-function-of-parent-window-when-child-window-closes)

But, the answer also preforms action on the child window which I think I can't do because the child window opens a website not in my control (I can't edit its html).

I was thinking of using the following to trigger the on close event

```
var inFormOrLink;
$('a').live('click', function() { inFormOrLink = true; });
$('form').bind('submit', function() { inFormOrLink = true; });

$(window).bind("beforeunload", function() { 
    return inFormOrLink;
})
```

How do I apply this on the new tab/window?

Comment: I've found something that could have been helpful but again they are preforming action on the child window.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777864/how-to-run-function-of-parent-window-when-child-window-closes

Comment: Do you have control over the original site that the child window loads?

Comment: Yes i do have control over the parent(original website) i do not have control over the child ones though if there is a way of adding the functions to the child windows then i could some how do it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible to do solely on the client-side. 
In order to do this, you'll need to do the following:

- Upon opening a tab, send an ajax call to a script that doesn't stop loading until it receives a second ajax call, this is usually done with a script that waits for an sql value to  exist before outputting.
- Upon closing the tab, send the second ajax call to that script so that it replies to the original ajax call.

Viola.

I'm not aware of a simpler way to do this.

**Original window:**

```
function waitForTabClose(windowID) {
    $.post('waitfortabclose.php',{windowID:windowID},function(data) {
        if (data == 1) { 
             // Do tab closed stuff
        } else {
            waitForTabClose(windowID);
        }
    });
}
```

**waitfortabclose.php**

```
$i=1;
$wID = $_POST['windowID'];
do {
    if (file_get_contents($wID) == $wID) {
        echo 1;exit;
    }
    set_time_limit(30);
    sleep(5);
} while($i++ < 50);
echo 0;
```

**New Tab**

```
window.onclose = function() {
    $.post('windowclosed.php',{windowID:windowID);
};
```

**windowclosed.php**

```
$wID = $_POST['windowID'];
file_put_contents($wID,$wID);
```

This is pseudocode, and hasn't been tested. The functionality can be written in a lot of ways, this is just how I'd do it.

Comment: wouldnt that requires me to have control over the second pop up window as well(sever side) ? the pop up window usually loads other websites which means i am unable to change anything server side there.

Comment: Then to be perfectly honest, I don't think it's possible.  You need some way of communicating between windows through the server, if not there isn't any way of you doing this.

Comment: Korin thanks for all your help and other but solution were found look at my answer

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution to what i were looking for. it was much easier then the above answer plus its actually works and what i were looking for.

```
var win = open('http://www.google.com');
if (win.closed) {
    alert('Window closed! Hoorah!');
}
```

Thanks very much for whoever tried helping.