# calling javascript function after pop up window close

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to run function of parent window when child window closes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777864/how-to-run-function-of-parent-window-when-child-window-closes)

Hi i have a link in a main page. when users click the link, it will open a popup window.

 **i need to call a javascript function in a main page after close the popup window how to do this?** 

can any one help me? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    window.opener.functionName();
}
```

Comment: not working: "Permission Denied"

Comment: "permission denied" normally means Same Origin Policy

Comment: exactly.. But the error is in IE only :(