# Run function after closing popup window in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

How can I run a function after closing the popup window?

This is my button click to open the popup window:

```
 ImageButton btnEdit = (ImageButton)sender;
 GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)btnEdit.NamingContainer;
 string url;
 url = "Add-Bank.aspx?a=E&id=" + txtEmployeeCode.Text.Trim() + "&acc=" + 
 ((HiddenField)row.FindControl("hidRecID")).Value;           
 Response.Write("<script>window.open('" + url + "',400,600);</script>");
```

And in my popup window, close button code is:

```
 this.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Close", "window.close()", true);
```

When I close the popup window how can I run the specific function or button click event?

What I tried is so far
I created one click even called btnRefresh:

```
 protected void btnRefresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   LoadData();
 }
```

I tried to run this event from popup window but it's not hitting the event as:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
  var cpframe = top.document.getElementById('contframe');
  if (cpframe) {
   cpframe.contentWindow.document.getElementById('Main_btnRefresh').click();
   }
   });

 </script>
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is `Main_btnRefresh` control?

Comment: In parent window

Comment: Take a look at :https://stackoverflow.com/a/1777985/7124761

Comment: Let me know if is working for you or not

Comment: i tried that with this function             function RefreshParent() {
                window.opener.document.getElementById('Main_btnRefresh').click();
                window.close();
            } did not get it working also

Comment: Can you produce a demo?

Comment: produce a demo i dont get it? i search about this issue before i post here and i tried some solutions, one of the solution is above code. Refreshparent function i created under popup window.