# Call function in parent window when child close button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a requirement that I need to call a parent page function when the child window close button is clicked.

How can I do this in jQuery or JavaScript?

Thanks in advance

Comment: OK so firstly, bolding your question doesn't make people more likely to answer it and your going to want to show some sort of attempt. If not an attempt at least some of your code so that anybody mad enough to help you has something to go by.

Comment: SO has a "requirement" that you need to try something by yourself, and if you get stucked, post the failed code and ask, what went wrong ;).

Comment: Anyways, what are you good at `javascript` or `jquery`?

Comment: Yeah, don't bold the whole question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run function of parent window when child window closes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112340/how-to-run-function-of-parent-window-when-child-window-closes)

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to use [onunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onunload) function . like this

`window.onunload = function (e) {
      window.parent.functonToCallonThisWindowCloses();
    };`.

So that  function of parent  is called when child window is closed.

Answer (score 0):

The only reliable, cross browser, cross domain solution I have found to do this is poll the window.closed property of the child from the parent:

```
setTimeout(function() {  
    if(child.closed)
    { 
        functionToBeCalledWhenClosed();
        return;
    }
    setTimeout(arguments.callee, 0);
}, 0);
```

Instead of 0, you can use any interval that is acceptable to you in your application.